# NullReferenceException was unhandled by usercode in mvc application using linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling below method in my controller.

```
 var comments = _blogService.GetBlogComments(bc.CommentParentID);//Controller code
```

class code:

```
public virtual IList<BlogComment> GetBlogComments(int CommentParentId)
        {
            if (CommentParentId != 0)
            {
                var query = from bc in _blogCommentRepository.Table
                            where bc.CommentParentID == CommentParentId
                            select bc;

                var comments = query.ToList();
                return comments;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

I am getting error on

```
var query = from bc in _blogCommentRepository.Table
                            where bc.CommentParentID == CommentParentId
                            select bc;][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMWcV.jpg

Comment: probably your `_blogCommentRepository` is null. Where are you initializing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to bind is that the `_blogCommentRepository` variable that you are using inside the `GetBlogComments` method is `null`. So make sure that this variable is initialized before using it:

```
_blogCommentRepository = new ...
```

Comment: how to initialized to _blogCommentRepository.Table?

Comment: That will depend on what `_blogCommentRepository` is, how you are accessing the data, etc ... Basically you need to create a new instance of the type using the constructor of this type.